# How to put a line break in xmldoc comments

Tags: delphi, xml-documentation

I have a following summary snippet.

```
  /// <summary>
  ///  Holds the future state for 4 pixels
  ///  Every pixel can be in 4 states, on, off, unknown, or don't care
  ///  Off=00, on=01, unknown = 10, don't care = 11.
  ///   The grid is like this:
  ///   <code>
  ///      TL|TR        <br/>
  ///     ---+---       <br/>
  ///      BL|BR        <br/>
  ///  </code>
  /// </summary>
```

This is displayed in the popup hint as:

> Holds the future state for 4 pixels
>      Every pixel can be in 4 states,
>      on, off, unknown, or don't care
>      Off=00, on=01, unknown = 10,
>   don't care = 11.
>      The grid is like this:
>      
>      `TL|TR         ---+---        BL|BR`

The ascii art in the middle is correctly shown in monospaced font, but no line breaks.
How to I get the line breaks to be displayed correctly

Comment: The answer is to be found in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML_Documentation_Comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use paragraph break **<para/>**:

```xml
/// <summary>
/// The grid is like this:
/// <code>
///      TL|TR        <para/>
///     ---+---       <para/>
///      BL|BR        <para/>
/// </code>
/// </summary>
```

Result:

[image]